# Is there a way to construct a grpc server on a connected socket net.conn?

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

The typical usage in go is:

```golang
    server := grpc.NewServer()
    
    pb.RegisterUserServer(server, &userSrvc.UserServer{})

    addr := ":" + env.GetMyRpcPort()

    lis, _ := net.Listen("tcp", addr)

    server.Serve(lis)
```

I wonder can I run a server on a connected conn like:

```golang
conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp",":8080")
server.Serve(conn)
```

The client connect to the server first, and then construct a grpc server on the connected net.conn, then the server can rpc call the client to push some message as a request to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need a [bidirectional streaming](https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/core-concepts/).
Here is one elaborated example of using bidirectional GRPC in Go: https://github.com/pahanini/go-grpc-bidirectional-streaming-example.

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial(":50005", grpc.WithInsecure())
...
client := pb.NewMathClient(conn)
stream, err := client.Max(context.Background())
...
req := pb.Request{Num: rnd}
err := stream.Send(&req)
```